# Removing unwanted table cell borders with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a peculiar and frustrating problem. For the simple markup:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th></tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b></td><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr class='odd'><td>x</td><td>y</td><td>z</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I apply different background-color values to the *thead*, *tr*, and *tr* odd elements. The problem is that in most browsers, every cell has an unwanted border which is not the color of any of the table rows. Only in Firefox 3.5 does the table have no borders in any cell.

I'd just like to know how to remove these borders in the other major browsers so that the only thing you see in the table are the alternating row colors.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who suggested adding border-collapse:collapse to the CSS. That did it.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

You need to add this to your CSS:

```
table { border-collapse:collapse }
```

Comment: Note that this has to be applied to the _table_, not the _td_'s. I just made this mistake and spent upwards of half an hour trying to figure out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 33):

to remove the border , juste using css like this :

```
td {
 border-style : hidden!important;
}
```

Comment: pretty straightforward and works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: I know long time pasted, but your answer really helped me, without any `border-collapse`! Upvote + thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Modify your HTML like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b></td><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr class='odd'><td>x</td><td>y</td><td>z</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

(I added `border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"`)

In CSS, you could do the following:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Set the `cellspacing` attribute of the table to `0`.

You can also use the CSS style, `border-spacing: 0`, but only if you don't need to support older versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to add

```
table td { border:0; }
```

the above is equivalent to setting cellpadding="0"

it gets rid of the padding automatically added to cells by browsers which may depend on doctype and/or any CSS used to reset default browser styles

Comment: Cellpadding is the space between the table content and its boundries `td{padding:X}`. Cellspacing is the space between each cell's bourdries ("margin" between cell borders). You can set `border-collapse` to mimic what the `cellspacing` attribute does on the table tag, but it's not foolproof.

Answer (score 1):

After trying the above suggestions, the only thing that worked for me was changing the border attribute to "0" in the following sections of a child theme's style.css (do a "Find" operation to locate each one -- the following are just snippets):

```
.comment-content table {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;

.comment-content td {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 0;
}
```

Thus looking like this afterwards:

```
.comment-content table {
    border-bottom: 0;

.comment-content td {
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the style of `border: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;` to the table element.

Comment: @Josh isn't it `border: none`?

Comment: @DougNeiner Old post, but none and 0 are both equally valid. I like 0 because I have to type less :)

Answer (score -1):

sometimes even after clearing `border`s.

the reason is that you have images inside the `td`, giving the images `display:block` solves it.