# Table border shown in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I use WKHTMLTOPDF to generate a pdf.
On my page, I have a table with no border. 
In the browser everything is fine.
Example of table:

```
<table class="noborder" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="noborder">
            <th colspan="2" class="noborder">MyHeader</th>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS: Noborder:

```
.noborder {
    border: 0px solid black;
}
```

But in the generated PDF there are the borders.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the pdf only show borders when you open it in the browser? When I open my PDF in Mac via the standard viewer, it displays correctly. It's only when I render within Chrome that I have this issue. It also displays as expected in Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am having the exact same problem. In browser everything renders ok. But when I render in pdf, borders appear in all tables. I had to use tables because wkhtml and pdfkit were not able to interpret div class row and div class col; consequently text never appeared as desired in the pdf.

However this seems to work:

```
td {
    border-style : hidden!important;
   }
```

This was reported: [Removing unwanted table cell borders with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039438/removing-unwanted-table-cell-borders-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

I know its a late answer, but none of the above worked for me.
Only some of the table cells required a border by design, so adding transparent border to all cells fixed it.

```
.c-info-table td,
.c-info-table th{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.c-info-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td{
    background-color: #ecf2f6;
}
```

[image: before / after]